# Making sense of Rails TimeZone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, timezone, ruby-on-rails-3

Consider this gist: https://gist.github.com/752934

When converting from String to Time everything goes well. It returns as UTC. However, when you convert from time to time it returns as WEST instead of UTC (or returning self: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-to_time)

Any idea on why is the time zone being changed from UTC to WEST?

Thanks in advance,
DBA

Comment: Is your question really _"why does this occur?"_ or is it _"how can I get a time or date that is time-zone independent?"_

Comment: My question is how can I preserve the TimeZone throughout the chain of invocations.

Comment: Also, it's odd that ActiveSupport Time core_ext sets Time.to_time to return self, which shouldn't lose the timezone.

Comment: Given that you have a string representing only a date, do you really need a `Time` instance, or would a [`Date`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/index.html) be more appropriate?

Comment: @Phrogz we need time, as the user can input more than just the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing it suffers from the same problem as DateTime.to_time.  This was submitted as a bug in Ruby, but rejected.  More info here:

http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/3737

UPDATE:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/conversions.rb

Looks like API doc is out of date.  There is a condition on the method to check if to_time is already defined.  So looks like its not even hitting this ext method:

```
  # A method to keep Time, Date and DateTime instances interchangeable on conversions.
  # In this case, it simply returns +self+.
  def to_time
    self
  end unless method_defined?(:to_time)
```

Here is the commit: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4817bf94d135c44ddfae1a30acb15de989e3c86c/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/conversions.rb

I tested out monkey patching and it works like you would expect:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > class Time
ruby-1.9.2-p0 ?>  def to_time
ruby-1.9.2-p0 ?>    self
ruby-1.9.2-p0 ?>  end
ruby-1.9.2-p0 ?>end
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Time.zone = Time.zone_default = "UTC"
 => "UTC" 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > t = "2008-04-01".to_time
 => 2008-04-01 00:00:00 UTC 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 >  p t.zone, t.to_time.zone
"UTC"
"UTC"
 => ["UTC", "UTC"]
```

I would consider this a bug

Comment: Indeed, though I really don't understand that behavior in the parsing API.

Comment: ahh.. I see what you mean after looking at the source in the rails api.  Looks like it is not really returning self.

Comment: I'm surprised it's not up to date.  That commit was a year and a half ago.  I figured the docs were automated from source.